# `tbb::parallel_reduce` making copies?

Tags: c++, tbb

According to https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506154 the functional form of the `Reduction` operator is `Value Reduction::operator()(const Value& x, const Value& y) const`. It is called like this:

```
template<typename Range, typename Value, typename RealBody, typename Reduction>
void lambda_reduce_body<Range, Value, RealBody, Reduction>::join( lambda_reduce_body& rhs ) {
    my_value = my_reduction(const_cast<const Value&>(my_value), const_cast<const Value&>(rhs.my_value));
}
```

Is there any reason it doesn't instead take rvalue references? For example, suppose my reduction operation is concatenating a bunch of results. It could do `my_value = my_reduction(std::move(my_value), std::move(rhs.my_value));` where `my_reduction` could be

```
[](std::vector<T>&& lhs, std::vector<T>&& rhs) { 
    lhs.insert(lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    return lhs;
}
```

That would let `my_value`'s memory be reused.

Comment: There is no reason other than the code being written back in 2008 and not revisited since then. I suggest you open an issue at https://github.com/intel/tbb, or even contribute a patch.

Comment: Here's a sketch of it: https://github.com/intel/tbb/pull/169